# mosquitto_sub and grep to trigger command/action

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I can use `mosquitto_sub` to subscribe to broker for a specific topic, say *test_topic*,

`mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic`

I can also pipe grep for a specific keyword, say *valve_closed*,

`mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic | grep "valve_closed"`

This would  only output a newline with "valve_closed", every time that particular topic broadcasts "valve closed" message.

Input,

Line 1: `mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic | grep "valve_open"`

Line 2: `mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic | grep "valve_closed"`

Output,

Line 1: `valve_closed`

---

Now, my question is, how can I pipe a command such that if `grep "valve_closed"` is true, then execute another command.

I've tried chaining a command like `echo "Okay so now Valve is Closed"` with another `|` pipe command,

`mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic | grep "valve_closed" | echo "Okay, so now Valve is Closed"`

But this simply runs the echo command with output `"Okay, so now Valve is Closed"`, even when I group grep+echo within parentheses.

I also tried using AND operator `&&`,

`mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic | grep "valve_closed" && echo "Okay, so now Valve is Closed"`

While this waits for grep to match string `valve_closed` as soon as it finds a match, it would execute `echo "Okay, so now Valve is Closed"`.

I've also tried using if statement, however any inclusion of conditional statement seems to break the polling nature of `message_sub` which constantly monitors a given topic and prints out its output.

I'm kind of lost as to how I can use mosquitto_sub to retrieve messages and execute shell commands/scripts based on message content. Thanks for reading.

Comment: xargs should work for you for this. Research using xargs with grep. Come back and ask if you were not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
mosquitto_sub -h MOSQUITTO_BROKER_HOSTNAME -t test_topic | grep "valve_open" | some_other_script_to_handle_the_output.sh

#!/bin/bash
#content of some_other_script_to_handle_the_output.sh example script
echo "Input parameter: $1"
exit 0
```

That's one of the beautiful things about the pipe "|".  They can be chained together.

That other script could effect changes elsewhere in a myriad of ways.  Based on the frequency of these MQTT responses, you would want that script to finish quickly so things don't get backed up, but usually that's not a problem.  Trial and error is your friend here and could lead you to a more efficient methodology down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `mosquitto_sub` never returns (by default) so it's output never ends so can't be used to test against.

You will do MUCH better not trying to do this in a shell script and use something like python.

Edit:

If you REALLY MUST do this without writing something (trust me it is worth it) then you can use mqtt-exec (though it would require nodejs installing)

https://github.com/denschu/mqtt-exec

Comment: If you design testtopic to only have trigger messages (ie. messages that you want to act on), then use -C 1 to exit on any message received. Else, if you still insist on mosquitto_sub, then put it in a loop, at the risk of missing messages...

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in one of my earlier iterations and guess what - there's an inherent delay between the time a message is received and ```mosquitto_sub``` realizing it's fulfilled ```-C 1``` condition. Sometimes the order of that delay is upwards of a second, which defeats purpose of low latency nature of MQTT broadcast messages.

Comment: Well, looks like user error because when I tried the minimal reproduction against a local broker, the mosquitto_sub exited immediately after a mosquitto_pub, unless you have long latency between your clients and your broker, then that's an entirely new problem. You will not solve your problem unless you are meticulous and precise.